# Public DNS (IPv4) gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a t2.large EC2 instance running with an elastic IP. Whenever I choose to reboot the Instance, it gives a "This site can’t be reached, .... refused to connect." error.

I have tried rebooting it via SSH and also creating the a new instance from a snapshot. Creating a new instance does work but that's obviously not a solution. I have tested the url on different ISPs and all of them give the same error. What could be going wrong here?

I have also made sure that the Security group does allow Inbound traffic from my IP.

Comment: You mentioned both Public DNS and EIP, they are different stuff.  Did you ping the EIP ?   DId you disabled the EC2 instance auto-ip assignment ?

Comment: @mootmoot: IPv4 Public IP and Elastic IP are the same in my console. I have not disabled the auto-ip assignment manually.

Comment: Is everything looks something this ?  
https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HoL0Ubhb-XA/WAHUFWQhC2I/AAAAAAAAMog/0UrnMHs2IL0J-2JYGpinsFiNLZHjh9nkQCLcB/s1600/ipchanged.png

Comment: @mootmoot Not really.. http://prntscr.com/kyx863 this is how it looks.

Comment: No matter whether I use the "ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com" or the Elastic IP, the page gives the same error.

Comment: Perhaps this ? 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205941/how-to-fix-error-this-site-can-t-be-reached-for-a-site-installed-on-amazon

Comment: that doesn't look like the solution. I have already checked the Security Group and made sure the Port 80 is open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180847/discussion-between-rahul-and-mootmoot).

Answer (score 0):

Turn out a simple `sudo service httpd restart` does the trick. You can try restarting it twice if you get a [FAILED] for `Stopping httpd:` and [OK] for only `Starting httpd:`

You have to make sure you allow Inbound Traffic from your IP in your Security Group before giving this a try.